# how to get value of int field name from mysql in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the values from a table in which some fields names are integer.

below is my table

```
|--------------------|
|  id   |  1   | 2   |
|--------------------|
|  1    |  6   | 3   |
|  2    |  8   | 6   |
----------------------
```

I tried below code in normal php its working but in codeigniter its not working

```
 mysqli_query($conn,'select `1`from table')  //normal php working.
 $this->db->query('select `1` from table'); // not working in ci.
```

Comment: no errors...if i write as *,'1' getting only id.

Comment: how about `select * from table`?

Comment: same getting id value only

Comment: try `$this->db->query('select table.1 as one from table');`

Comment: Try this -- this should work. $this->db->query("select table-name.".$i." from table-name");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to run query either using active records or SQL Query
Try This

```
function get()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('table',1);
    return $query->result();
}
```

OR

```
$query=$this->db->query('select table.1 as one from table');
$query->result();
```

Comment: second one is working. for static it is fine . if i need all fields in table

Comment: just replace this **'select * from table'** for getting all fields

Comment: try this **'select id,table.1 as one,table.2 as two from table'**

Comment: my fields are created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `result()` in the end:

```
//get results
$result = $this->db->query('select table.`1` from table')->result();

//parse results
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row; //complete row
    //OR
    echo $row->1; //cell value
}
```

Comment: out put is same null

Comment: Are you receiving it in a variable or not? LIke:  `$result  = $this->db->query('select table.1 from table');`

Comment: $result is getting null

Comment: query: $this->db->query('select tbl_distance.1 from tbl_distance')->result();print_r($query);exit;   o/p:Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( ) [1] => stdClass Object ( ))

Comment: You need to loop through the result set to get values one by one. Try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
 $this->db->query('select 1 from table'); OR
```

OR Try this:--

```
 $this->db->query('select "'.1.'" from table');
```

Comment: getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.1'

Comment: Try this;--  $this->db->query('select table-name.".1." from table');

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"1" from tbl_distance' at line 1

select tbl_distance."1" from tbl_distance

Comment: Try this --  this should work. $this->db->query("select table-name.".$i." from table-name");